# How to access listview items generated by arrayadapter

Tags: android, listview, firebase

I have tied my application to Firebase database and after being able to display them I also want to be able to select them and access their textview values. However .getValue() does not work for views. I know that my code is very messy and my selector is only working one way, but can you help me to find out what is going on. I will add a screenshot to make things more clear. At the moment when clicking on one of the items int num = Integer.parseInt(text) gives an error and the app will crash because the value I get from view is "Android.widget...", not what I want to get.
Screenshot pic:

[image: Screenshot]

Orders.java

```
public class Orders extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String TOTAL_SUM = "com.nordscript.checkmate.SUM";

// Declare the UI components
    private ListView foodList;

    // Declare an ArrayAdapter that we use to join the data set and the ListView
    // is the way of type safe, means you only can pass Strings to this array
    //Anyway ArrayAdapter supports only TextView
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    private Firebase ref;
    private Orders activ;
    private ArrayList<String> dishes;
    public int total;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    activ = this;
    dishes = new ArrayList<String>(20);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);

 // Initialize the UI components
    foodList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Create a reference to a Firebase location
    ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio-demo.com/Restaurants/Restaurant 2/Tables/Table 2/Orders");

    // Read data and react to changes
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
            Map s = snapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            dishes.add(snapshot.getName() + "  " + ((Map)snapshot.getValue(Map.class)).get("Price"));
            Log.i("Test", dishes.toString());
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(activ, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dishes.toArray());

            // By using setAdapter method, you plugged the ListView with adapter
            foodList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          }

          @Override public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) { }

          @Override public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Map s = snapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            dishes.remove(snapshot.getName() + "  " + ((Map)snapshot.getValue(Map.class)).get("Price"));
            Log.i("Test", dishes.toString());
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(activ, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dishes.toArray());

            // By using setAdapter method, you plugged the ListView with adapter
            foodList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
          }

          @Override public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) { }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) { }
    });

    foodList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            String text = view.toString();
            text.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
            int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
            total += num;
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.orders, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void toPayment(View view) {
    Intent pay = new Intent(this, PaymentMethod.class);
    pay.putExtra(TOTAL_SUM, total);
    startActivity(pay);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i understand from your question : Suppose when you click on 3rd item i.e "pudding 8", you want this value "pudding 8"(textview value). right?? 
 If that so than you just have to get values from your ArrayList which you pass to the adapter on first place with the help of position attribute inside your `setOnItemClickListener` like this :

```
foodList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            String text = dishes.get(position);
            // do what you want to do with this value.

        }
    });
```

Comment: When I put your line into there, now I get a NumberFormatException with keeping the rest of the code. However I managed to get the right value now.

Comment: @Heiki - the above solution is only to get your STRING VALUE , if you convert string(eg:"pudding 8") into integer it will give you that exception. if you need only integer value than tell me , i can help you with that.

Comment: The text.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""); did not work for me. I substituted it with                 String str = text.substring(text.indexOf(" "));
                int num = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
Isn't pretty but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Change your onClickListener() like that:

```
foodList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        String text = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        text.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
        int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
        total += num;
    }
});
```

Or you can use `SimpleAdapter` for displaying string and integer values separately using two textviews in a separate xml layout. Using that you can get values on `onclick()` in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to gettext of that particular view, `view.getText().toString();`

```
foodList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            String text = view.getText().toString();
            text.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
            int num = Integer.parseInt(text);
            total += num;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot call .getText() on views, you can only do that with textViews.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you, but it is bad way:

```
foodList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String item = (String) arrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            String[] split = item.split(" ");
            int num = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);
            total += num;
        }
    });
```

But it is very urge...

As for me, you need to extends Adapter, to collect into it your custom items, and after clicking gets it and takes integer value you need.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might become a little too late but, hope this
helps someone who was looking for similar solution to Custom ArrayAdapter with multiple values.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            ListItems item = (ListItems) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            System.out.println("Item: "+item.getName());
        }
    });
```